# Jquery $.each inside $.each using setTimout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use `setTimeout()` inside a nested `$.each`. When I run this script, `console.log` immediately shows immediately `main0,main1,main2` which is wrong and should be shown one by one after every 5 seconds like `test ...` values from the second `$.each`.

```
var i = 1;
var indexArrayMain = [1,2,3];
var indexArray = [3,6,9];
var timerx = new Array();

// main each
$(indexArrayMain).each(function(indexArrayMain) {
  console.log('main' + indexArrayMain);
  // sub each
  $(indexArray).each(function(indexArraykey) {
    function internalCallback(i, indexArraykey) {
      return function() {
        val = indexArray[indexArraykey];
        console.log("test " + i + val);
      }
    } 

    timerx[i] = setTimeout(internalCallback(i, indexArraykey), i * 5000);                     
    i++;
  }); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guxdz/8/

Comment: But you have no timeout for the first console.log, you simply loop over indexArrayMain and then call console.log immediately.

Comment: If you want the "main" output to happen in the timeout callback, shouldn't that line of code be in the callback function?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code, you'll see how the code is being executed and might help understand the flow of execution.  Chrome developer tools are a good start if you're not using them already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `console.log('main'+indexArrayMain);`
which is written under the first `$.each`, this log is not running inside the timeout callback, which makes it run immediately.

Comment: yes, but I need like this:

main0 - on start script
test 13 - after 5sec
test 26 - after 10sec
test 39 - after 20sec
main1 - after 25 sec.

... 
etc.

so, showing main1, main2 must be  depend from time used in setTimeout (second each)

Comment: I forked ur fiddle and added a setTimeout call for the first $.each. see if that is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/40nrx3ek/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait the timeout ends do run next item on array.

Try this:

```js
var indexArrayMain = [1,2,3];
var indexArray = [3,6,9];

var head = arr => arr[0]
var tail = arr => arr.slice(1)

function log(main, inner, i) {
 if (main.length === 0 || inner.length === 0) return console.log('end');
  console.log('main-'.concat(head(main)))
  console.log('inner-'.concat(head(inner)))
  setTimeout(log, i * 5000, tail(main), tail(inner), i++)
}

log(indexArrayMain, indexArray, 1)
```

Comment: thanks but it is not what I looking for. I need to show:
Main0 , inner0, inner2, inner3 , Main1, inner1 inner2, inner3. etc...

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout function creates a new execution cycle . to solving this problem you should know about javascript event loop and concurrency model.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the need for nested loops and to keep multiple options open (and for easier testing of the results), the arrays could be flattened beforehand. If I've gotten your setup right (the values of indexArrayMain don't seem to be used?), something like:

```js
let  i = 1, indexArrayMain = [1,2,3],
 indexArray = [3,6,9],
  arr = indexArrayMain.reduce((a,el,ind)=>{a.push('main' + ind);a.push(...indexArray.map(ind2 => 'test' + i++ +ind2 )); return a; } , []);

//imho using setInterval on the flattened array would be cleaner, but using the same setTimeout approach:
arr.forEach(function(el,ind){
 setTimeout(console.log.bind(null,el), ind * 5000);                     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> console.log immediately shows immediately main0,main1,main2

That's because you're printing those values immediately:

```
$(indexArrayMain).each(function(indexArrayMain) {
    console.log('main' + indexArrayMain);

    // other, unrelated code
});
```

There's nothing in that code to cause a delay, it simply loops over the collection and logs values to the console.

> should be shown one by one after every 5 seconds

Then you'd need to use something like `setTimeout` to introduce a delay.  If you want it to be "every 5 seconds" then that sounds like it would be the index of the collection plus one times five seconds.  So something like this:

```
$(indexArrayMain).each(function(indexArrayMain) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('main' + indexArrayMain);
    }, (indexArrayMain + 1) * 5000);

    // other, unrelated code
});
```

Note that this will be *independent* of your other timeouts, and the timing between them is not guaranteed to be exact.  If you want them to always execute in the same order, you'd want to use the same timeout instead of a separate one, or perhaps generally rethink the structure of what you're trying to do.  (Which isn't entirely clear, currently all you're doing is logging to the console so the order doesn't really matter.)